# Exposing a complex property in an ASP.NET user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I would like to expose a complex property from a custom ASP.NET user control, **in such a way that it can be set from the control tag in the aspx page**.

Something like this:

```
public class TestData {
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

public partial class TestControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl {

    public TestData TestProperty {
        get {
            return ViewState["TestProperty"] as TestData;
        }
        set {
            ViewState["TestProperty"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the .aspx file of a page that contains the control I would like to have something like:

```
<div>
    <testns:TestControl runat="server" ID="TestControl1" TestProperty="X:1,Y:2"/>
</div>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this? Or what didn't happen that you expected?

Comment: @Hans and Mattias, I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I've found out a couple of ways of doing that, and I thought they might be useful for someone else as well :)

To serialize the object in an attribute of the control, you have to define an appropriate `TypeConverter`, and apply a `TypeConverterAttribute` to the property type. Here is an example: [How to: Implement a Type Converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayybcxe5.aspx).

Even easier, you can persist the attribute in the control's content just like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="wbctrlstst._Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="x" TagName="TestControl" Src="~/TestControl.ascx" %>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <x:TestControl runat="server" ID="testlist1">
            <TestProperty X="1" Y="42" />
        </x:TestControl>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The only requirement, for what I could see, is that the type must have a default constructor. You can apply the `PersistenceModeAttribute` to the property to specify that the property should be persisted in the controls's contents, but it looks like it's the default behavior, and this is not strictly needed.

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
public TestData TestProperty {
    get {
        return ViewState["TestProperty"] as TestData;
    }
    set {
        ViewState["TestProperty"] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my answer then. I was so sure that you couldn't do this (I don't use webforms anymore though).

Comment: @Mattias: don't worry, I guess you were just trying to be helpful :)