# Initialize a Dictionary property in ASPX code

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, dictionary, properties

I am currently trying to initialize a Dictionary property of a UserControl through ASP.NET 2.0 code, and I cannot find a valid syntax.

Let's suppose I have a very simple UserControl with a Dictionary property:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;

public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Dict { get; set; }
}
```

How do I initialize it in a ASPX page?

I have tried different things, like this one under, but none worked:

```
<my:MyUserControl>
    <Dict>
        <dictionaryentry key="a_key" value="a_value" />
    </Dict>
</my:MyUserControl>
```

I have also tried to replace dictionaryentry with add or KeyValuePair, with no luck.

Does anybody knows a way to do that with plain ASPX code?
I could use C# in my page, but I look for a more "classy" solution.

Thank you for your answers.

--
Eric

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251179/exposing-a-complex-property-in-an-asp-net-user-control

Comment: Well, I have already seen this post, but it is for a custom class and not a simple dictionary. But thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not as simple as that - you have to expose a property that can hold collection and then have a editor type for that collection. See this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178654.aspx) for the example code.

Comment: It's a pity, but I must admit that I will have to rely on a custom class with a collection and not a simple dictionary.
Thanks for your answer.